Minimum number to maximize the chance of a certain average
What is the method to approach a question like the following.
In a test, each answer to a question gets a score between 0 and 100, both inclusive. It is a given fact that in the long run my average is 60. If the test included infinite numer of questions, my average would approach to 60. For a given question, it is possible that I may get any score between 0 and 100.
Question 1: Let us assume I need a 70 average for whatever reason. What would be the minimum number of questions to maximize my 70 average?
Question 2: On the first question I score 20. Now, what would be the minimum number of questions to maximize my 70 average?

What is the distribution of your answer scores? If your average is 60 but you always score between 55 and 65, then you have no chance to score above 70 no matter how many questions there are.

It depends on your distribution of scores. The answer may be "one question" if the aim is to maximise the probability of an average of $70$.

@Henry assuming scores are i.i.d, wouldn't one question always be correct? Even in the case David described, n=1 would still be a valid answer.

@ischmidt20 - yes, but the question does not say "independent"
